# Swift: How can I post data from three separate text fields onto labels in a custom cell, as the result of pressing a button?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am new to swift, and I am trying to take text from one textfield and values from two other text fields (one value from each text field) on a ViewController, and then when a button is pressed, have all three pieces of information displayed horizontally in a cell in a tableview.

This is an example of what I am trying am trying to do:

[image: example]

I would like the data from text fields one, two and three to be displayed in labels one, two and three, once the button is pressed.

Comment: What kinds of things have you tried? Do you have the table view set up with a data source as your view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@IBAction func btn_reload(sender: AnyObject) 
{
   /*lbl1.text = txtfield1.text!
   lbl2.text = txtfield2.text!
   lbl3.text = txtfield3.text!*/

   var arrmute: [AnyObject] = [AnyObject]()
   var arrmute2: [AnyObject] = [AnyObject]()
   var arrmute3: [AnyObject] = [AnyObject]()

   arrmute.append(txtfield1.text!)
   arrmute2.append(txtfield2.text!)
   arrmute3.append(txtfield3.text!)
   self.tbl_out.reloadData()

}
```

First setup set delegate and datasource of `UITabelView` in your storyboard.

Give reuseIdentifier of row as given in code: cell

Make outlet of your `UITableView`.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int 
{
    return arrmute.count
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{
    var cell: UITableViewCell
    if cell == nil 
    {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    cell.lbl1.text = arrmute[indexPath.row]
    cell.lbl2.text = arrmute2[indexPath.row]
    cell.lbl3.text = arrmute3[indexPath.row]
    return cell

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! One problem is that the data is being displayed in three separate rows, instead of horizontally across one row.